# В чем причины остановки работы программы?

Tags: c, массивы, строки, динамические-массивы

Вот две вырезки из программ

1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char* sentence = "Hello, friend's";

    sentence[5] = 'a';

    printf("%s", sentence);

    return 0;
}
```

2. 

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char sentence[] = "Hello, friend's";

    sentence[5] = 'a';

    printf("%s", sentence);

    return 0;
}
```

По моему мнению, они эквивалентны, но почему при выполнении первой программы на выходе нет ничего,  а выполнение второй программы идет полностью по сценарию (символ ',' заменился на 'a' и программа выводит результат - измененную строку)?

Доп. сведения:
Компилятор: gcc version 11.1.0 (GCC),
Язык: C,
Версия языка: C99.

Comment: Во втором случае вы пытаетесь изменить элемент изменяемого массива из 16 элементов char. А в первом - неизменяемого из 16 char const.

Comment: Но тогда я бы все равно мог выводить sentence[i] во втором случае, а я этого сделать не могу...

Comment: *"во втором случае, а я этого сделать не могу"* - в вопросе было написано *"а выполнение второй программы идет полностью по сценарию"*

Comment: Прошу прощения, в первом случае*

Comment: Попытка изменить элемент неизменяемого массива является неопределенным поведением. Скорее всего, первая программа просто падает на строке `sentence[5] = 'a';
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь

```
char* sentence = "Hello, friend's";
```

вы пытаетесь изменить литерал, который представляет собой константную строку, которая может быть размещена, например, в памяти "только для чтения". Что и приводит к неприятностям.

```
char sentence[] = "Hello, friend's";
```

создает *изменяемый* массив, который заполняется указанными инициализирующими символами. Изменение разрешено, массив не константный.

Comment: Но почему тогда при попытке выполнить эту строку в первом случае: printf("%c", sentence[5]); выводится белиберда?

Comment: Вопрос решен, спасибо, я понял в чем проблема)